# What's the significance of spitting up into the air in Jamaica Kincaid's "Girl"?

Tags: short-stories, jamaica-kincaid

Part of the advice given in Jamaica Kincaid's "Girl" is on how to spit:

> this is how to love a man, and if this doesn’t work there are other ways, and if they don’t work don’t feel too bad about giving up; this is how to spit up in the air if you feel like it, and this is how to move quick so that it doesn’t fall on you; this is how to make ends meet;

What's the significance of spitting up into the air (and making sure you don't get hit)? Why specifically up into the air? Why is this something significant enough that it's being taught mother-to-daughter?